# Virtual Attribute in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, virtual-attribute

I have a model of product and I need to write in the _form view , the  number of the product that an admin wants to insert.
I have another table with the Supply (number of product)
so in my product table I don't have the attribute quantity , but I have just the `supply_id` (that links my two tables of product and supply)

Since I don't have the quantity in my product table, I used a virtual attribute on Product.

I had to change the view of the new and edit product
cause in the new I want the field quantity but in the edit I don't want (cause I use another view to do this)
So, I deleted the partial _form and created separate view.
Also, I had to set in the controller of products that if I want to update a product, i have to call a set_quantity callback, cause I have to insert a "fake" value to fill the `params[:product][:quantity]`. This , because I setted the validation presence true ,on the quantity virtual field in the product model. I want to know , if all this story is right (it works , but I want a suggestion about the programming design of this story. Cause I don't like the fact that I give a fake value to fill the quantity field when I have to update a product)

Controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    include SavePicture 
    before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :set_quantita, only: [:update]
    ....

    def set_quantita
       params[:product][:quantita]=2  #fake value for the update action
    end
    ....
end
```

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :supply ,dependent: :destroy
    attr_accessor :quantita
    validates :quantita, presence:true
end
```

Can you say me if there is a better way to fill the `param[:product][:quantity]` in the case of the update action? Cause i don't like the fact that i give it the value of 2. Thank you.

Comment: since the supply is associated to the product you could use a nested form: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using `attr_accessor` you could create custom getter/setters on your product model. Note that these are not backed by an regular instance attribute.

Also you can [add a validation on the `supply` association](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated) instead of your virtual attribute.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supply ,dependent: :destroy
  validates_associated :supply, presence:true

  # getter method
  def quantita
    supply
  end

  def quantita=(val)
    if supply
      supply.update_attributes(value: val)
    else
      supply = Supply.create(value: val)
    end
  end
end
```

In Ruby assignment is actually done by message passing:

```
product.quantita = 1
```

Will call `product#quantita=`, with 1 as the argument.

Another alternative is to use [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) for the supply.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supply ,dependent: :destroy
  validates_associated :supply, presence:true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :supply
end
```

This means that `Product` accepts `supply_attributes` - a hash of attributes.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  #...
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    # will create both a Product and Supply
    @product = Product.create(product_params)
  end

  def update
    # will update both Product and Supply
    @product.update(product_params)
  end

  private

  def product_params
    # Remember to whitelist the nested parameters!
    params.require(:product)
          .allow(:foo, supply_attributes: [:foo, :bar])
  end
  # ...
end
```

Comment: The first alternative gives you maximum flexibility in creating the associated Suppy. The second is more of the "Rails Way" of solving the problem. I would go with nested attributes unless there is some really weird requirement that prevents you from doing so.

Comment: i ll try to understand your answer when i ll be a little free. Thank you :)